# Logged in VS Change password security issue

Tags: bug, security, password

I'm using same the login to access Stack Overflow from 3 different computers. Once I forgot my password, and had to recover/change it. When I try to access the Stack Overflow page on some computer, where I'm already logged in, it should log me out, or ask me to retype the password, but it doesn't.

Comment: Something to do with cookies I think.

Comment: Once you're authenticated, that authentication token is stored in a cookie, I'd imagine. Changing your password does not invalidate that token (even though perhaps it *should*).

Comment: hmm, I search for any other question, but I missed this one :(